# Automator folder action questions

Tags: automator, folders, folder-action

[As I asked in this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2992/whats-the-tool-that-can-do-some-actions-when-a-file-is-copied), I could make it that a file in a directory can be renamed automatically, but I have some questions about this action.

- Where to the workflow files are copied? When I run 'save as', it doesn't seem to show the directory where the file is copied.
- How is this folder action stored and restored so that it runs automatically when system reboots? In other words, I guess I don't have to rerun automator whenever I reboot, how does this possible?

### ADDED

1. I found that the automator workflow is stored in "~/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions/"
2. I also found that folder action from automator workflow is also registered by running "/System/Library/CoreServices/Folder Actions Setup.app"

Answer (score 1):

> Where to the workflow files are copied?

I don't understand this question.

> Is this folder action stored in a system so that it's working even after my reboot?

By default, folder actions are stored in the `/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts` folder.