# "readlink" gets the original path of a symlink; what's the equivalent for Mac aliases?

Tags: command-line, alias, symlink

In the terminal, I can use readlink on a symlink and it prints the target path of the symlink. E.g.

```
ln -s original.txt symlink.txt
readlink symlink.txt  # prints original.txt
```

How do I do this for Mac alias? I know the path is embedded in the resource fork, because the xattr command will display it in a raw format mixed with other data:

```
xattr -p -l com.apple.ResourceFork alias_file
```

However, I don't know enough about this format to extract it. I found the perl Mac::Files man page, but it has no examples, and Google was no help with it.

Maybe there's a way to use osascript to do it, similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8102/how-to-make-an-alias-cmd-l-using-command-line) answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more googling, I was able to pull together the pieces for an osascript command:

```
alias_path="your/alias/path"
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"' -e "posix path of (original item of alias file (posix file \"$alias_path\") as text)" -e 'end tell'
```